# Ajax contact form is not sending 'message' field in email

Tags: php, ajax, forms, email, post

I've set up my form and I'm  unsure why the email is being sent and received, but does not include the 'message' field.

I have tried changing the ID's and testing different options but it doesn't seem to send the message

I had the issue a while back with another website but I was able to fix it and I don't remember how.

The reference used is $comment and I've used id=comment so I'm unsure why it's not sending it! Any help much appreciated. I've read other posts on here and no one has a similar issue from what I know.

Here is my website code:

```
<!-- Form -->`    `
            <form method="post" action="/contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform" class="form form-stacked c-form">
                <fieldset>
                    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
                    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" />
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    <input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" size="4" value="" placeholder="3 + 1 =" />
                    <input type="submit" class="submit btn outline" id="submit" value="Send message" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Here is my contact form .php

```
    <?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
//$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($comment) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a message.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
}

/*
if(trim($subject) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a subject.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($comment) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isset($verify) || trim($verify) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the verification number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
    exit();
}
*/

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comment = stripslashes($comment);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

$address = "support@idomain.sx";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'Email from: ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comment\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<strong class=\"success\">Email Sent Successfully.</strong>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, please allow up to 5 business days for a response.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your textarea is named `comments`

```
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
```

But here it's looking for `comment`

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
```

Make sure the name is the same as the `$_POST` variable

**Remember** form data is appended to the name of the input, not the id

EDIT

```
$e_content = "\"$comment\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

You aren't concatenating your string and variable. Change it to:

```
$e_content = $comment . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

I don't know what the backslashes are for. If they are required, change it to:

```
$e_content = "\" . $comment . "\" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Sorry I copy and pasted the source code of the template, it is currently set to comment and yet no message comes through. 

I've just changed it again and retested the email and I receive this
    
 
  
 

 



You have been contacted by Tom with regards to , their additional
message is as follows.

""

Comment: I have set the form data name to comment and the reference is 'comment' in the php file. Still doesn't work. Any other advice :)?

Comment: If I use 
------
$e_content = "\" . $comment . "\" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
------
I get syntax error ------
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in /home2/guide/public_html/firework.com.au/contact.php on line 69
------and if I use-----$e_content = $comment . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;-----I get no message at all, not even the double brackets

Answer (score 0):

Change the $comment = $_POST['comment'];

into

$comment = $_POST['comments'];

Answer (score 0):

Your textarea is named comments

```
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
```

But here it is looking for comment

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
```

Make sure the name is the same as the $_POST variable. Remember that form data is appended to the name of the input, not the id.

Edit:

```
$e_content = "\"$comment\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

You aren't concatenating your string and variable. Change it to:

```
$e_content = $comment . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

I don't know what the backslashes are for. If they are required, change it to:

```
$e_content = "\" . $comment . "\" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is recommended to make use of formatting options.